# Substitute Average of Previous and Next Available Values of Field for NA Values in Dataframe

Tags: r, average, na, na.approx

The sample data set of available much bigger data set is in following format:

```
Station <-c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A")
Parameter <-c(2,3,NA,4,4,9,NA,NA,10,15,NA,NA,NA,18,20)
Par_Count <-c(1,1,1,2,2,1,2,2,1,1,3,3,3,1,1)

df<-data.frame(Station, Parameter, Par_Count)
df
Station  Parameter  Par_Count
   A        2          1
   A        3          1
   A        NA         1
   A        4          2
   A        4          2
   A        9          1
   A        NA         2
   A        NA         2
   A        10         1
   A        15         1
   A        NA         3
   A        NA         3
   A        NA         3
   A        18         1
   A        20         1
```

I want to approximate NA's which are less than 2 in number with average of next and previous available values for NA in that column. In original data set somewhere NA's are 100's in number, so I want to ignore consecutive NA's greater than 3 in number.  Par_Count represent number of consecutive occurrences of that particular value in parameter.
I tried with:
    
    `library(zoo)
    df1 <- within(df, na.approx(df$Parameter, maxgap = 2))`

and even for for single occurence with:
    
    `df1 <- within(df, Parameter[Parameter == is.na(df$Parameter) & Par_Count == 1] <- 
    lead(Parameter) - lag(Parameter))`

but nothing worked. It didn't change any occurrence of NA value.
The desired output is like:

```
Station  Parameter  Par_Count
       A        2          1
       A        3          1
       A        3.5        1
       A        4          2
       A        4          2
       A        9          1
       A        9.5        2
       A        9.75       2  <--here 9.5 will also work
       A        10         1
       A        15         1
       A        NA         3
       A        NA         3
       A        NA         3
       A        18         1
       A        20         1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are nearly there.  I think you have misinterpreted the use of `within`.  If you would like to use within, You need to assign the output of na.approx to a column of the data frame.  The following will work:

```
library(zoo)
df1 <- within(df, Parameter <- na.approx(Parameter, maxgap = 2, na.rm = FALSE))
```

Note it is advisable to use na.rm = FALSE, otherwise leading or trailing NAs will be removed, leading to an error.

Personally, I think the following is more readable, though it is a matter of style.

```
library(zoo)
df1 <- df
df1$Parameter <- na.approx(df$Parameter, maxgap = 2, na.rm = FALSE))
```